# Comcast Xfinity TV videos will not launch

Tags: 12.04

just installed ubuntu 12.04 lts on my old XP desktop. Now xfinity TV will not launch videos. I get the ads, the TV rating, but the video will not launch. Recieving no error messages, just hangs on the ad or the rating page. Any ideas anybody?

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this as well. It looks like they use Flash for ads, but Silverlight for the content. Sadly, there is no proper Silverlight support for Linux.

Quickest way around this is to install [wine](http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu), then install the Windows version of [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all/), and just use the win32 Firefox for viewing XFinity (or anything else Silverlight, ie Netflix).

Comment: follow this instructions : http://froebe.net/blog/2012/11/18/howto-watch-xfinity-on-demand-video-on-ubuntu-12-04-12-10-32bit-64bit/

Comment: @Private IIRC, the Silverlight patches are now in upstream wine. No need to run patched wine anymore :)

Comment: @SlightlyCuban downloaded/installed wine and win32 firefox. Video prompted me to install flash. Downloaded/install win32 flash, now firefox crashes when try to watch. Not sure why flash video is not playing in linux firefox.